# Approval Process automatic rejection

Tags: approval-process

I'm currently working on an app in which we're using approval process for bookings. We want to make the rejection process happen automatically after 2 days but we're not sure how to implement that inside the process itself. We've been thinking about creating custom trigger in order to do that but we're not sure if that's the best solution. Appreciate any help.

Comment: My first thought is a time-based workflow rule, but I'm not sure a workflow action can be rejection. A scheduled flow (that specifically queries for records that qualify for rejection) or a scheduled batch would also work if it's OK for them to run each day at a set time.

Comment: Well, the problem is that this automatic rejection should be fired after 2 days, counting from the moment when Approval was fired so I guess the scheduled batch won't do the trick this time

Comment: You could have a time-based workflow rule that is initiated from the approval process, after 48 hours a field on the record changes and from the object's trigger you could reject it.